# Is there a way to install older Laravel-Auditing versions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auditing

I am using **Laravel 5.4**, **PHP 7.0.30** and **Ubuntu**. As I type the command `sudo composer require owen-it/laravel-auditing` to install Laravel-Auditing, I get the following errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/css-selector v4.1.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/css-selector v4.1.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/css-selector v4.1.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector == 4.1.4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v4.1.4].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

It's not feasible to upgrade PHP version right now either.

Please help !

Comment: Don't use sudo for composer. Wanted package doesn't make an issue with your configuration, you can check requirements in `composer.json` file.

Comment: @Tpojka, what may I check in **composer.json** ?

Comment: In composer.json file of that package (NOT your application composer.json) but [`owen-it/laravel-auditing`'s](https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing/blob/master/composer.json) you can check that mentioned package supports Laravel 5.4 and PHP >=7.0.13 which your current environment has.

Comment: @Tpojka I was eventually able to install Laravel-Auditing by upgrading my PHP to 7.2.9. Phewww!

Comment: I didn't read well. Yup, your PHP version wasn't ok for that package. Good you solved it.